# Access an element in a vector of pairs by a key besides find_if() or iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, lookup, stdvector, std-pair

So i have a vector of pairs which contains another vector of pairs written like this (The same as a 2D vector but the 'int' serves somewhat like a key to the element):

```
struct Item
{
    string word = "";
    int count[3] = {0, 0, 0};
};

vector< pair<int, vector< pair<int, Item> > > > MyWords;
```

Currently, the way I access a unique element given the two integer keys is like this:

```
//Find the pair with a key == key1 in the main vector
auto it1 = find_if(MyWords.begin(), MyWords.end(), 
           [](const pair<int, vector<pair<int, Item> > >& element){
               return element.first == key1;
           });

//Find the pair with a key == key2 in the vector that has a key == key1
auto it2 = find_if(it1 -> second.begin(), it1 -> second.end(),
           [](const pair<int, Item>& element){
               return element.first == key2;
           });

//Access the element using the returned iterator
it2 -> second.count[0] = A_Number_Here;
```

I'm trying to find a better way to access an element like using the keys like an index (The keys start from 0). Unfortunately, using [] results to a segmentation fault:

```
MyWords[key1].second[key2].second.count[0] = A_Number_Here;
```

Any other ideas? I know that there are other STL Containers like map and set but I'm currently trying to do it with a vector.

By the way, I would also like to ask what is the time complexity of find_if()?

Edit: The keys of the pairs may not be consecutive (0,1,2,3 ...)

Comment: @HehwBoi are your so called `keys` **unique** and starting from index 0 to n-1, where n = `MyWords.size()`?

Comment: Shouldn't you use the returned iterator to access an element? eg it2->count[0]

Comment: @JeJo Yes, it starts from 0

Comment: @Ian4264 You mean it2->second.count[0]? That's what I'm currently doing but I'm trying to find a different way to access an element

Comment: Yes, forgot about second

Comment: Not clear. So is the first part of your question (using `find_if`) how you're successfully _currently_ doing it, and the second part of your question (using `operator[]` like a lookup) how you're unsuccessfully _trying_ to do it, but thereby getting a seg fault?

Comment: @acraig5075 I'm just looking for a better way to access an element aside from using find_if() or iterators

Comment: The `find_if` way looks perfectly good to me - it's clear in what it does. If your actual problem is there's too much typing for your liking, then just put it in a `SetItemCount(key1, key2, number);` function.

Comment: @acraig5075 Thanks for the suggestion :), but I'm wondering why it looks perfectly good to you though. I mean like, would it be slow enough if for example it is going to find an element in a set of 10000 elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to access an element by using the keys like an index.
>   Unfortunately, I always receive a segmentation fault.
>
> ```
> MyWords[key1].second[key2].second.count[0] = A_Number_Here;
> ```
>
> Any other ideas?

First of all, its tedious to do such a vector-data structure. You should probably, re-think of data-structure requirements and should come up with something lighter. Secondly, There is **nothing wrong** in your way of accessing. Its correct. **[SEE THIS](https://www.ideone.com/gkCdQL)**

Probably, you are providing wrong keys(`key1` and `key2`) to access the vector content. One thing to note that, the key-pair that you introduced will not work as expected, since `std::vector` is not `std::map`.

When you do `MyWords[key1]. and rest.....`, and for instance `Key1 = 0`, you are accesing the first element of the vector `MyWords`, where the first `int` could be any value.(not necessarily `0`, as you mentioned you have an unsorted vector). I think you are assuming this to happens and trying some values greater than `MyWords.size()`.

The solution to your problem is to either use the **[iterator based looping/ accessing](https://www.ideone.com/JcVqza)**, which will only show what you have got inside or stick with `std::find_if`, as it will return end of vector iterator, in case of key not being found inside.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Item
{
   std::string word;
   std::vector<int> count; // changed to vector array
};
using Pair = std::pair<int, std::vector< std::pair<int, Item> > >;

int main()
{
   std::vector< Pair > MyWords =
   {  //int, <std::pair<int,          Item            > > >
      {1   , {        {    4,  Item{"String1", {1,2,3}} } }       },
      {0   , {        {    5,  Item{"String2", {5,2,8}} } }       },
      {2   , {        {    8,  Item{"String3", {1,7,9}} }, {    9,  Item{"String4", {11,77,99}} } }       }
   };

   for(const auto& bigPair: MyWords)
   {
      std::cout << "Key : " << bigPair.first;

      for(const auto& smallPair: bigPair.second)
      {
         std::cout << "\nValues: " << smallPair.first << "\t";

         std::cout << smallPair.second.word << " "
                  << smallPair.second.count[0] << " "
                  << smallPair.second.count[1] << " "
                  << smallPair.second.count[2] ;
      }
      std::cout << "\n\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

> I would also like to ask what is the time complexity of find_if()?

[`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) can have an time complexity, **up to linear** in the distance between `first` and `last` iterator, according to the `predicate` you provide, which will search for each element until a match is found.

As an alter native you could use [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) with a custom lambda/ predicate(to only return when finds a match, otherwise it will also returns the iterator pointing to **next greater** element in the vector, if available) **after you sorted** the `MyWords` vector according to the first value(key). `std::lower_bound` has only time complexity of *O(longn)*, which will be much faster than `std::find_if`.